# Are there wood sealers that are safe for fresh or saltwater marine use?

Tags: deck, sealing

I have a wood dock over a lake.  It is time to clean and seal the dock.  I am planning on pressure washing the dock first, then I am planning to have a clear seal.  Looking at products in Lowe's and Depot I can't determine what is safe to use. I don't want it to look like a BP spill or kill any life forms.

Comment: @Tester: Going for that Copy Editor badge? :)

Comment: @Doresoom: Just trying to clean up the "Thanks" at the end of questions. I just couldn't take it anymore!!! Wish they would write a script to get rid of it, like they did to remove the salutations at the beginning of questions.

Comment: @Tester: Feel free to be OCD (I've been know to have such tendencies from time to time myself). I'm just giving you a hard time.

Comment: Are we talking "deck" or "dock" here?

Comment: @Carl technically a dock.  It's built just like a deck and when I posted the question it was the closest tag.  I didn't have the rep to add a tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do make stain [specifically for marine use](http://saversystems.com/wood-products/marine-seal-wood-dock-stain).  Doesn't say specifically that it's environmentally friendly, but the MSDS sheet does say it's water soluble.  The same manufacturer has [environmentally friendly stains](http://saversystems.com/wood-products/uv-resistant-clear-finish) as well, but I have no idea how well they might work (or exactly what "environmentally friendly" means to them).